# Make a JSON Google Maps Link with Lat Log given coordinates

Tags: json

I have Address and Lat/Long coordinates. trying to figure out how to make a Google Maps link with either set of information. I do not know if there is another way of making link smaller.

When Searching for this Lat/Long,30.445616 -84.28166, I get this link on web
[https://www.google.com/maps/place/30%C2%B026'44.2%22N+84%C2%B016'54.0%22W/@30.4456206,-84.2842403,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d30.445616!4d-84.28166?entry=ttu](https://www.google.com/maps/place/30%C2%B026%2744.2%22N+84%C2%B016%2754.0%22W/@30.4456206,-84.2842403,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d30.445616!4d-84.28166?entry=ttu)

When searching for address, 327 N Adams St, Tallahassee, FL 32301, I get this link
https://www.google.com/maps/place/327+N+Adams+St,+Tallahassee,+FL+32301/@30.4456211,-84.2842113,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x88ecf57773d11d49:0x2f06db4113ed9163!8m2!3d30.4456165!4d-84.281631!16s%2Fg%2F11b8z0x1ww?entry=ttu

my variables are lat_1 and long_1

Sorry, I am new in JSON scripting

<a href=href=https://www.google.com/maps/@$lat_1$,$long_1$>link text
doesnt work, gives my location, instead of information I enter